# Sudden Javascript Google Oauth2 problems

Tags: javascript, oauth

I'm using Google Oauth2 Javascript in a JSP application.

```
 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>

 function googleOAuth(idx) {
alert ("Please ensure that popup windows are enabled in your browser. You will      authenticate directly with Google in another window.");
   var config = {
    'client_id': '<%=googleClientId%>',
    'scope': 'https://mail.google.com/ https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'response_type': 'token',
    'immediate': false
  };
  gapi.auth.authorize(config, function() {
     var token = gapi.auth.getToken();
   /// ...use token

  });
  }
```

My app was working fine till yesterday, today its failing to authorize
and the Chrome console says:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
at line cb=gapi.loaded_0:223
The handler function has not executed yet.
Line 223 has the following:

```
var f=c.popup,g=c.after_redirect;f&&"keep_open"!=g&&(0,_.Uu)(window,f)
```

and I don't see how g&&(0,_.Uu)(window,f)
can be valid JS.

Is anyone else seeing this too?

Comment: I ran into this problem as well and thought I had made a bad change on my own, but it turns out I wasn't alone. I should point out, however, that `g&&(0,_.Uu)(window,f)` is valid JavaScript. It makes use of the comma operator, which returns the value of the second operand. In order for it to make sense here, the value of `_.Uu` should be a function, because it is immediately called after evaluating the expression. In order to see that `g&&(0,_.Uu)(window,f)` is indeed valid, try running it in your console after first executing `var g=true,_={Uu:alert},f=null`.

Comment: I see; You're right (though I suspect the intended usage is g && g(0, _.Uu)(window,f). This idiom is used in several places). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug. Also reported:
[one](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-api-javascript-client/XB2tzHbfyd8)
[two](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/issues/detail?id=103)

Google as I know is fixing now.